# Gridview disappears if there is no result

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a gridview that has as datasource the standard SqlDataSource1. A user can change the query based on a dropdown and this works fine. But when there is no result the whole gridview disappears.
This is the code that gets activated when the dropdown is changed, it's fairly simple but to just give an example on what I am doing:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * from Kist where Rij ='" + DropDownList1.Text + "'";
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Why do you call SqlDataSource1 a standard? And I'd challenge your assertion that adjusting the query based on a dropdown works fine - you have a great recipe for a SQL Injection attack because you [didn't use a parameterized query](https://bobby-tables.com/). And finally, the GridView is working as expected. If there's no rows, it won't be visible. If you want to display a text message when that happens, set the [EmptyDataText property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatext#System_Web_UI_WebControls_GridView_EmptyDataText) of the GridView.

Comment: To expand upon masons excellent comment, the danger of not using parameterised queries extends beyond SQL Injection attacks. I hear so many people say that it is a test app, or internal, so security is not a concern, but this is besides the point. It also allows query plan caching, so you don't need to recompile the query for every parameter, but it also prevents malformed SQL. Suppose your drop down list has an item that is `Tim O'Shea`, the apostrophe will not be escaped and you will end up with a syntax error. Another issue is type safety, as this approach can lead to conversion errors too

Comment: @mason, thanks for your informative answer! I know the query is very standard and can easily lead to a SQL injection. But by using a dropdown this wouldn't be the case right? Because there is no user input, the user can only select a certain list and can not edit this list. Besides that, is there a option that the header of the gridview just stays, because otherwise I have to refresh the whole page to search again with the dropdown..

Comment: @LucSil You're falling into a trap. Just because your UI is obtaining the value from a dropdown doesn't mean that you're safe. If you're taking data from a client, you must assume the client can manipulate the data. A user can run JavaScript in their browser to manipulate the items within the dropdown, or construct an entirely custom HTTP request with whatever they want in it. Why would your search box disappear if the GridView isn't visible? Did you declare your search box in an inappropriate location?

Comment: @mason, damn thanks a lot. Didn't know that could happen. I will definitely look into that. The dropdown does not disappear but when I change the value in the dropdown that has results it does not work anymore because the gridview is totally gone.

Comment: @mason "Why do you call SqlDataSource1 a standard?" seriously? he's just saying he's using a standard SqlDataSource control.

Comment: @mason, It was indeed to just make the question easier to understand, but this does not really matter. I still got the problem that my Gridview disappears, it does not come back if I change the dropdown to a value that has a result.

Comment: I don't know why saying something is standard when it's not clear what you mean by that makes it easier. If you didn't mean anything specific by it, feel free to remove it from the question. As far as debugging your issue, you'll need to create a [MCVE] which should help you narrow down the problem.